# I found that I can get into my Arch Linux without a password. How to solve?

Tags: security, grub, arch-linux

I was able to enter the linux Archive without password with the GRUB boot command

```
quiet init=/bin/bash
```

and I was still able to edit root files!

Is this safe?

in this case, whoever steals the notebook would have access to a lot of things, how do I solve this?

Comment: You were not able to run that command without first already having access to the system. You can further mitigate the situation by using FDE. There isn’t enough specific information to provide further advice or to generate an actual answer

Comment: I didn't understand, I just turned on the notebook and, in GRUB, I pressed "e", and, without any initial password, I typed the given command and with /bin/nano, I was able to edit and save the service file *.service, and other SUDO files. When I restarted the system normally with a password, all modifications were active!

Comment: What @Ramhound is saying is that its only dangerous if you let someone else have access to your system, ie that attack requires physical presence. If you use encrypt you drive, as suggested, then the attacker must know your password. So is it safe? Nothing is safe. It all depends on your threat model. Its reasonably safe if you guard your computer 24/7 and you live in Antarctica. If you're worried, then just encrypt it.